# How to find all the links in a webpage that has a specific file extension?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to find a `href` in a website that has a certain file extension. for example it would print `http://www.test.com/something.mp3` `http://www.test.com/somelinktoamuscifile.mp3` `http://www.test.com/music.mp3`.

It would show all of links, with a file extension of `.mp3` for example.

would you do 
`var extension = ".mp3"`

`var checker = url + extension`

`if(url == checker){console.log(url);}`

Comment: Try matching the html with a regexp like `/href(\s+)?=(\s+)?["'](.*)\.mp3["']/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to extract all links that contain a certain string from any given url?
Maybe this script will help you:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
var toFind = "delete"  //use file extension or whatever you want to find

request(url, function(err, resp, body) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('a').each(function (i, element) {
        var a = $(this);
        //console.log(a.attr('href'));

        var href = a.attr('href');
        if (href && href.indexOf(toFind) != -1) {
            console.log(href);
        }
    })
})

Output:
$ node scraping.js 
http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/49991/should-yes-delete-it-be-red-or-green
```

Just change the content of `url` and `toFind`. There is a good tutorial on web scraping [here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-nodejs) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-use-node-js-request-and-cheerio-to-set-up-simple-web-scraping). Of course this can be done in a lot of different programming languages. I merely used javascript because you tagged it that way.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a native javascript solution that works in current browsers (IE8+, Chrome, Firefox) without jQuery.

```
function getLinksWithExtension(extension) {
    var links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href$="' + extension + '"]'),
        i;

    for (i=0; i<links.length; i++){
        console.log(links[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I put your code into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CFn9V/). To see the output just press F12(chrome,ff) and open the console.

Comment: @ruthless I wrote a small script which works for arbitrary websites and search strings. see answer below

Answer (score 0):

I think it goes like this:

```
var mp3_extension = '.mp3';
var url_string = url.split('.');
var url_extension = url_string[url_string.length-1];

if(url_extension === mp3_extension){

    //go go go!!!     

}
```